# Rewrite Python OR Calculated Column

Tags: python, pandas

i am creating a new column. It will reference text in column A (test 3 string conditions) and the result will be text from column B.  I have this code and it works, BUT wondering if there is a cleaner better way to accomplish this task. Psuedo code would be: if 'linemove' column contains any of these strings, bring result form 'Home' column.

```
melted.loc[(melted['linemove'] == 'bigger dog') | (melted['linemove'] == 'flipped, now dog') | (melted['linemove'] == 'smaller favorite'), 'betOn'] = melted['Home']
melted.loc[(melted['linemove'] == 'smaller dog') | (melted['linemove'] == 'flipped, now favorite') | (melted['linemove'] == 'bigger favorite'), 'betOn'] = melted['Road']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way, maybe shorter to do this is to use `np.select` and `.isin` method

```
import numpy as np
melted['betOn'] = np.select(
                      [ (melted['linemove'].isin(['bigger dog','flipped, now dog','smaller favorite']),
                        (melted['linemove'].isin(['smaller dog','flipped, now favorite','bigger favorite']),
                      [ melted['Home'], # what to use when condition1 is true
                        melted['Road'] ], # what to use when condition2 is true
                      default = melted['betOn'])
```

Since you only have two conditions you can also simply do

```
melted.loc[melted['linemove'].isin(['smaller dog','flipped, now favorite','bigger favorite']), 'betOn'] = melted.loc[melted['linemove'].isin(['smaller dog','flipped, now favorite','bigger favorite']), 'Home']
melted.loc[melted['linemove'].isin(['smaller dog','flipped, now favorite','bigger favorite']), 'betOn'] = melted.loc[melted['linemove'].isin(['smaller dog','flipped, now favorite','bigger favorite']), 'Home']
```

The advantage of `np.select` method is that you don't have to locate twice you rows (left and right sides)

Comment: i agree, i like the select method better. thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's hard to shorten the `or` as ultimately that's the logic you're trying to implement.

You could make it more readable by defining an array of the boolean output, and then use that to set the values, e.g.;

```
my_condition = melted[ (melted['linemove'] == 'bigger dog') | (melted['linemove'] == 'flipped, now dog') | (melted['linemove'] == 'smaller favorite') ]

melted.loc[ my_condition, 'betOn' ] = melted.loc[ my_condition, 'Home' ]
```

And give `my_condition` a meaningful name (I really struggled to understand the context of your condition to name it well!).

Comment: no worries, thanks for the help. i like this method. its a bit easier to read